# AWS Amplify S3 Protected File - Lambda Function Invocation

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-amplify

I have a file saved as a 'protected' file in a S3 bucket. I have setup (through CLI) a lambda function to trigger when a file is added to the bucket. Lambda function works as intended for the public files. However for the protected files, when  i try to access the file via the lambda function (s3.GetObject), i'm getting the following error:

**An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.**

I have the relevant policies setup to gain access to the S3 bucket and right now pretty much exhausted all the options. Really appreciate someone point me at the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Found what's causing the issue. The 'folder' in the bucket contained a ':'. When the bucket name and key passed into the lambda trigger, it was encoded. So the ':' turned to a %3A hence the NoSuchKey error.

In order to address that, i've decoded the key back to normal form in python.